# Planet view in pannellum.js

Tags: javascript, pannellum

Effect example: [CLICK](https://mapyinwestycji.pl/deweloperzy/tbv/osiedleeuropejskie/)

Is it possible to make an animation like in the example - zooming in from the "planet" view?

I'm using [pannelum.js](https://pannellum.org/).

```
const viewer = pannellum.viewer('panorama', {
            "type": "cubemap",
            "cubeMap": [
                "cube/front.jpg",
                "cube/right.jpg",
                "cube/back.jpg",
                "cube/left.jpg",
                "cube/top.jpg",
                "cube/down-1.jpg"
            ],
            "maxLevel": 20,
            "autoLoad": true,
            "hotSpots": [
                <?php foreach ($hotspots as $hotspot): ?>
                    {
                        pitch: "<?php echo $hotspot['pitch']; ?>",
                        yaw: "<?php echo $hotspot['yaw']; ?>",
                        cssClass: "custom-hotspot",
                        createTooltipFunc: hotspotFn,
                        createTooltipArgs: "<?php echo $hotspot['name']; ?>",
                        name: "<?php echo $hotspot['name']; ?>",
                        category: "<?php echo $hotspot['category']; ?>",
                        marker: "<?php echo $hotspot['marker']; ?>",
                        <?php if ($zalogowany): ?>
                            clickHandlerFunc: hotspotClickFn,
                            id: <?php echo $hotspot['id']; ?>,
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    },
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            ]
        });
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+panellum+zoom+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.